# Including .pde files from different directories than root

Tags: java, processing

Basically a very simple question:

I know that say I have my folder `Sketch` I can create a `Sketch.pde` file and Processing will then run that `Sketch.pde` as my `main` file if I ask VSCode to build a new version of my sketch.

Now I now that if I want to store a class not in my `Sketch.pde` file, I can just create `ClassName.pde` and write my `class ClassName { ... }` code in there.

I am currently on an assignment where we're going to use Processing version >3 to make a game. To have some organization for our git folder, i'd like to seperate my different class files into different folders under `Sketch`. Say all files that belong to the group `enemies` under `Sketch\Enemies\<ClassName>.pde`.

I noticed Processing won't recognize classes stored in directories other than the `main` file by using the normal Syntax I'm used to. Is it possible to do something alike to `Enemies = Sketch\Enemies`?

**TLDR** Can you include class files from a child folder of the root directory of your main file.

Comment: The idea is you _don't_ create files yourself. The PDE does that for you, and shows each file as a tab in your sketch, so dir structure is not something that applies to Processing sketches. If you're not using the PDE and you want to organize your code, then by all means do but then you'll also need to symlink each file into the main dir, so that Processing can see it.

Comment: I guess symlinking could work for this purpose. I might try that out.

I find this [the idea that you don't create files yourself] a somewhat frustrating feature of the PDE actually. I know it's built to get people into coding, but abstracting the fact that the tabs are actually different files on your computer is kind of odd to me.. that just keeps the computer illiterate that way?

i've had a bunch of people ask why their programs broke because they moved their main .pde file but not the other class files the PDE had created for them.

Comment: it makes the PDE great for PoC code, but not all that great for full blown graphics projects that are just small enough to still warrant using Processing. Remember that Processing is not intended for programmers, it's intended for everyone, and for everyone "it does things so you don't even need to know it's a thing other languages bother with" is _pretty great_. File structure should only matter once that's something _want_ to care about, and then George's suggestion to just use Eclipse (etc) with the processing running is your best continued approach.

Comment: As for people asking about moving .pde files: don't move files, move the sketch. And per Processing convention, a sketch is an entire folder, and that's where the knowledge can comfortably end =)

Comment: That's what I told them! I've just noticed how people asked me 'How do I create a new tab' after switching IDE's - they had no idea about .pde files in the first place, they thought of them as tabs. Thanks for your input either way!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unfortunately Processing (AFAIK) will only take into account .pde on the same level, but not in subfolders/packages.

If you absolutely must use the Processing IDE it you might need to go with a flat folder structure (all .pde files in the same sketch folder).

In the end all .pde files get clustered into a single .java file anyway.

If it's java packages and a better editor you're after then feel free to use any IDE with java project support (haven't tried VSCode, but IntelliJ / eclipse / etc. will work). 
Once you've setup a raw java project, you can use Processing's core.jar library.

You should check out [Kevin Workman's Processing in Java tutorial](https://happycoding.io/tutorials/java/processing-in-java) which has very nicely detailed explanations.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply.

I had a feeling Processing wouldn't support this directly. Good suggestion, I'll surely try that some time, but as the program eventually has to run directly on the Processing IDE (all other project groups are using it), I'll just keep it organized in this messy way for now. Saves me some potential troubleshooting.